# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - (36. Valid Sudoku on Leetcode)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

all.

I am working on this problem which comes from Leetcode.

Here is the link if anyone want to see the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/

I think I almost solve this problem, but something wrong with the "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" which I used capital comment in my code to mark it out, ==> "if (brain[((int) board[x][y]) - 1])"

I checked it many times and I think the indexes should be perfectly fine within 0~8 by doing "for( int i = 0, i < 9; i++)" and I could not find the reason.

I guess this must be easy stupid question, but I kinda spend a lot of time to find it out. Can someone help me out?

BIG THANKS to whoever help!

```
  public class Solution {
        public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {
            if (board.length > 9 || board[0].length > 9 || board == null) {
                return false;
            }

        boolean[] brain;
        // 9 digits are corresponding to 1 ~ 9 ==> 0 - 1, 1 - 2 ... 8 - 9
        // ex: brain[2] is checking for digit "3" , so using brain[3-1] to check "3"

        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
                if (board[x][y] != '.') {


                    // THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM!!!


                    if (brain[((int) board[x][y]) - 1]) {

                        // my condition failed by using:
                        //                                                  brain[board[x][y] - 1]
                        // other's condition Partially passed by using
                        // (still failed for final submission:
                        //                                                  brain[(int) (board[x][y] - '1')]
                        // need to compare the difference


                        return false;
                    } else {
                        brain[((int) board[x][y]) - 1] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
                if (board[x][y] != '.') {
                    if (brain[((int) board[y][x]) - 1]) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        brain[((int) board[y][x]) - 1] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        for (int block = 0; block < 9; block++) {
            // Reset brain
            brain = new boolean[9];
            for (int r = block / 3 * 3; r < block / 3 * 3 + 3; r++) {
                for (int c = block % 3 * 3; c < block % 3 * 3 + 3; c++) {
                    if (board[r][c] != '.') {
                        if (brain[((int) board[r][c]) - 1]) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            brain[((int) board[r][c]) - 1] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't shout at us, please. :-)

Comment: @Kratos_Omega Are you sure board[x][y] cannot contain 0?. Lol btw leri

Comment: you are trying to cast a `char` to `int`. This doesn´t return `1` for the `char` `1`. My guess is that you are trying to acces an index somewhere between `47-57`, but that would only be visible to us with the complete stacktrace

Comment: @Nadir `board` is a `char` array, which he casts as `int`, so even with `0` in there it should be the index `47` if i didn´t missread it.

Comment: @KevinEsche you are right, its overflowing the array for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast a `char` as `int`. Try to manually cast these values and you will notice that `0=48` and `9=57`, which i guess should be the cause of your exception.

You might want to check if the value in there represents a number and get the numeric value of the `char` by using the `Character#getNumericValue` method.

```
if (Character.isDigit(board[x][y]) && 
    brain[Character.getNumericValue(board[x][y])) - 1]) { 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all, (int) is the problem which I forgot it will actually grab the actual value of char instead of digit value.

Well, I try it again by using KevinEsche's if statement & also try my new if statement, which is "if (brain[board[x][y] - '1']) { ... }", but same error happens at the 2nd loop again. 

I will mark Kevin's answer as completed, since it does point out my problem, and still thx to everyone helped.

But, just ask if anyone possibly know what might cause the same problem in the 2nd loop, even after I added correct index (I believe I did)?

Comment: Well, I think the problem is the '.', which I didn't filter it out of my calculation properly, the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException return "-3", which indicate the "period" get involve with calculation of - '1'.